# C grading test score using pointers - segfault after 4 entries

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm taking C++ class at school and decided to study C on my own. Trying to make a small program that is calculating the average grade of my class and displaying the letter grade of students. When I input the score of students, my code stops after I input 4 values and displays segmentation fault. 
I'm pretty sure this is the reason, but not sure how to fix it.
I would appreciate any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

double Average(double * scores, int N) {
    int i;
    double total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        total = total + scores[i];
    }
    return total / N;
}

int Agrade(double * scores, int N) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scores[i] >= 90 && scores[i] <= 100) count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int Bgrade(double * scores, int N) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scores[i] >= 80 && scores[i] < 90) count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int Cgrade(double * scores, int N) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scores[i] >= 70 && scores[i] < 80) count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int Dgrade(double * scores, int N) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scores[i] >= 60 && scores[i] < 70) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
int Fgrade(double * scores, int N) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scores[i] < 60) count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    int N;
    double * scores;

    printf("How many test scores? ");
    scanf("%d", & N);
    if (N < 1) {
        printf("Invalid input. try again");
    } else if (N > 25) {
        printf("1-25 only.");
    } else if (N > 0 && N < 25) {
        printf("Total number of test is: %d\n", N);
    }

    double * scores = malloc(N * sizeof(double)); /* allocate the memory for N students */
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Enter the score of students: ");
        scanf("%lf", & scores[i]);
    }
    double averagescore = Average(scores, N);
    int scoreAcount = Agrade(scores, N);
    int scoreBcount = Bgrade(scores, N);
    int scoreCcount = Cgrade(scores, N);
    int scoreDcount = Dgrade(scores, N);
    int scoreFcount = Fgrade(scores, N);
    printf("The average test score : %lf", averagescore);
    printf("The number of A grades : %d\n", scoreAcount);
    printf("The number of B grades : %d\n", scoreBcount);
    printf("The number of C grades : %d\n", scoreCcount);
    printf("The number of D grades : %d\n", scoreDcount);
    printf("The number of F grades : %d\n", scoreFcount);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i < sizeof(N)` should be `i < N` in for loop.

Comment: `averagescore` is double variable and you printed using `%d` in `printf("The average test score : %d\n", averagescore);` use `%lf` instead. Compile your program with `-Wall -pedantic` flag.

Comment: You should restore line 73 so that the problem isn't already solved in the question, confusing future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the below code block of your code.

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(N); i++) { /* sizeof(N) is wrong */
    printf("Enter the score of students: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);/* putting data into N ? its wrong */
}
double averagescore = Average(scores, N); /* calling averagescore() with scores which is uninitialized & contain nothing ? */
```

It should be

```
double *scores = malloc(N * sizeof(double));/* allocate the memory for N students */
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("Enter the score of students: ");
    scanf("%lf",&scores[i]);
}
```

Here is the working one

```
 int main(){
            int i;
            int N;
            printf("How many test scores? "); //Number of students. Trying to calculate up to 25 students
            scanf("%d",&N);
            if(N<1){
                    printf("Invalid input. try again");
            }
            else if(N>25)
            {
                    printf("1-25 only.");
            }
            else if(N>0 && N<25){
                    printf("Total number of test is: %d\n", N);
            }
            double *scores = malloc(N * sizeof(double));/* allocate the memory for N students */
            for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    printf("Enter the score of students: ");
                    scanf("%lf",&scores[i]);
            }
            double averagescore = Average(scores, N);
            int scoreAcount = Agrade(scores, N);
            int scoreBcount = Bgrade(scores, N);
            int scoreCcount = Cgrade(scores, N);
            int scoreDcount = Dgrade(scores, N);
            int scoreFcount = Fgrade(scores, N);
            printf("The average test score : %f\n", averagescore);
            printf("The number of A grades : %d\n", scoreAcount);
            printf("The number of B grades : %d\n", scoreBcount);
            printf("The number of C grades : %d\n", scoreCcount);
            printf("The number of D grades : %d\n", scoreDcount);
            printf("The number of F grades : %d\n", scoreFcount);
            return 0;
  }
```

Learn how to debug a small code.

Comment: Thank you! but I still have a problem. I compiled the code with codelite and online compiler but both of them have an error.
main.c:86:9: error: redeclaration of 'scores' with no linkage

or

redeclaration of '*double scores'
Why is that?

Comment: error: redeclaration of '*double scores' 
sorry. I entered without writing error message.

Comment: Obviously you declared `scores` twice. keep it one. I added only `main()` function in my answer, remaining unchanged.

Comment: Thank you so much! I still have 'malloc' was not declared in this scope
error, but online compiler works. I'll just believe my compiler has a problem. thank you again and have a great day!

Comment: include the header `#include<stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 0):

The function sizeof returns the number of bytes your variable 'N' contains. You dont want that! You should replace sizeof(N) by N in order to read from the input N numbers. Also you should check your code in the loop because it isn't right!

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof(N)
```

This is wrong. `N` is already an integer, so asking for the size is useless, unless you're trying to allocate some memory to hold an int, which you aren't.